# What's Wrong With This PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-error

I'm getting this syntax error: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' on line 18** on [this page](http://www.glamourunderground.com/?p=505).

I think it's the 'first published' line that could be the problem. Any suggestions?

Thanks - Tara

```
<?php 
    $days = round((date('U') - get_the_time('U')) / (60*60*24));
    if ($days==0) {
        echo "Published today |"; 
    }
    elseif ($days==1) {
        echo "Published yesterday |"; 
    }
    else {
        echo "First published " the_time('F - j - Y') " |";
    } 
?>
&nbsp;Last updated at <?php the_time('g:i a'); ?> on <?php the_time('l, F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author(); ?>
```

Comment: Reference: [String operators in the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: Note that the parser actually **tells you** which line has problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is this:

```
echo "First published " the_time('F - j - Y') " |";
```

The other answers that suggest concatenation are all wrong. the_time(), in WordPress, will echo, so you need to split this in multiple calls:

```
echo "First published ";
the_time('F - j - Y');
echo " |";
```

Alternatively, concatenate but using get_the_time():

```
echo "First published " . get_the_time('F - j - Y') . " |";
```

Comment: Did you down-vote everyones answers? Considering that there is nothing in the question stating that this is Wordpress, and that the_time() is a Wordpress function, it's really not our fault if the question is incomplete.

Comment: @AdrianSchmidt: I was going to point out that it was in the tags, but then I realized Denis added that himself.

Comment: @Adrian: I'm quite aware it's not your fault, and quite honestly no offense was intended at all. A close look at his code (the `<?php the_time('g:i a'); ?>` call) was a hint that the function probably echos. Even without knowing WordPress, this makes the answers invalid. A simple concatenation will output something like `[date]First published |`. (And the answers had been upvoted to the point where Tara might have tried the wrong thing and come back for more help.)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer. I got a little irritated, but am no longer :) Good that you re-tagged the question too.

Comment: gotta agree with Denis on this one, the_time(), from what the OP's logic suggest, does already print, thus all the other answers are incorrect

Comment: All right, I updated my answer. I don't expect anyone to up-vote it, since Denis was the one who solved it, but can people at least please stop down-voting it now? :)

Comment: Sorry guys! I should have mentioned it was Wordpress. I should be getting the down votes! @adrian @denis Thanks for your help :) This worked.

Comment: `echo "First published ", the_time('F - j - Y'), echo " |";` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
echo "First published " the_time('F - j - Y') " |";
```

Try

```
echo "First published " . get_the_time('F - j - Y') . " |";
```

By using [get_the_time()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time) instead of [the_time()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_time), you can echo this concatenated with the rest of your string instead of having to break it into multiple lines.  Where Wordpress functions like the_time() echo their results, there is often a "get" version that returns the value without echoing it.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment on why they chose to downvote?

Comment: See the discussion under Denis' answer. I up-voted you, since I don't think it was our fault that the question asker did not mention using Wordpress functions...

Comment: @Adrian: Thanks for the note.  I updated my answer with get_the_time().  I was thinking that the functions sounded kind of like Wordpress, but I didn't connect the dots without the WP tag on the question.  Thanks for helping me figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

If this is indeed code from Wordpress, and the_time() echoes by itself, yes, then you need to put the echoes on separate lines:

```
echo "First string";
the_time();
echo "second string";
```

Sidenote:

When the parser complains that you are missing a semicolon (;), I find there are two very common reasons:

1: The error you have here; the parser finds and illegal character on the line. Having a function call right after a string literal (without a line terminator, like semi-colon, or an operator like . between them) will cause the parser output an error, and the parser will then guess that maybe you forgot to terminate the line here.

2: You actually forgot to terminate the line. But then the parser will complain about the line on which it finds the illegal character, and usually, you will want to tack the semi-colon on at the end of the line above:

```
myFunction() // <-- Oops, missing a semi-colon!
myOtherFunction();
```

Comment: BTW, who is down-voting completely valid answers? Please leave a comment explaining why when down-voting. It's common courtesy...

Comment: I did. I added a separate answer explaining why.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the concat operator (the dot).

```
echo "First published " . the_time('F - j - Y') . " |";
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to fix this.

The first is the same way everyone else did it: String concatenation:

```
echo "First published " . the_time('F - j - Y') . " |";
```

The other way is to add commas between each string.  The reason this works is because [`echo`](http://php.net/echo) takes multiple arguments.

```
echo "First published ", the_time('F - j - Y'), " |";
```

I don't know whether it's faster than string concatenation, though.